# Some images not loading in React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, web-development-server

I am a beginner in programming and I encountered a problem when running my React project. After running `npm start`, I found that some image resources were not packaged, causing some image resources to disappear when running the website locally.

For example, the homePageBackground.png image can be loaded normally and can be found in the source code of Chrome, but the Illustrations folder is missing:

I have tried checking the project configuration file, clearing the cache and reinstalling dependencies, but the problem still exists.

---

This is my project structure:

```
- public
  - images
    - homePage
      - homePageBackground
        - homePageBackground.png
      - Illustrations
        - ForestPath.png
- src
  - App.js
- package.json
```

---

This is how I reference image resources in App.js:

```
<img
  src={
    process.env.PUBLIC_URL + 
    '/images/homePage/homePageBackground/homePageBackground.png'
  }
  alt="Home Page Background"
/>
<img
  src={
    process.env.PUBLIC_URL + 
    '/images/homePage/Illustrations/ForestPath.png'
  }
  alt="Forest Path"
/>
```

Does anyone know the cause of this problem? How can I solve this problem?

This is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow, so please let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

I tried checking the project configuration file, clearing the cache and reinstalling dependencies, but the problem still persists. I expected all image resources to be correctly packaged, but in reality, some image resources disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to fix this issue

**Option 1:**
You can map images directly from public folder. No need to use `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` for that. `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` will not help in local dev, that's why you should avoid this.

Example:

```
<img src="/images/homePage/homePageBackground/homePageBackground.png" alt="Home Page Background" />
<img src="/images/homePage/Illustrations/ForestPath.png" alt="Forest Path" />
```

**Option 2:**
Import Images
You can import images like any other module. But you have to move the images from `public` folder to `src` folder. In the below example, I moved the `images` folder in `src` folder

Example:

```
import homePageBackground from './images/homePage/homePageBackground/homePageBackground.png';
import forestPath from './images/homePage/Illustrations/ForestPath.png';


<img src={homePageBackground} alt="Home Page Background" />
<img src={forestPath} alt="Forest Path" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.   
The first method is a good suggestion, but it doesn’t work for my problem. I found that `/homePageBackground/homePageBackground.png` can be loaded, but `/Illustrations/ForestPath.png` is not loaded.   
The second method can solve this problem, but if there are many images, it would be tedious to import them one by one.